# UIPickerView User Interaction Single Wheel

Tags: iphone

Does anyone know of a way to disable user interaction on a single wheel in a multi-wheel UIPickerView control?

Comment: Well, no answers on this one.  I ended up changing my design/UI to make it OK for both wheels to spin when needed.

Answer (score 1):

Use UIView to create a transparent overlay and trap the user input.